# How to find all minimum elements in a vector

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, by the function min（）， I can only get one single minimum element of a vector, even if there can be several equal minimum elements. I was wondering how to get the indices of all minimum elements in a vector?

For example,

```
v=[1,1];
```

I would like to get the indices 1 and 2, both of which index the smallest elements 1.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `find` to find the min values:

```
find(v == min(v))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
v = [1 2 3 1 5];
find( v == min(v) )

ans = 1 4
```

At least in Octave (don't have matlab), this returns the indexes of all minimums in v